# SQL: Count rows where column value changed from previous row

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql

Suppose I have Oracle or Postgresql database.

```
 ID         IdExample  OrderByColumn   What I want 
---------- ---------- ----------      ----------              
   1         1       1300                 1              
   2         1       2450                 1              
   3         2       5000                 2               
   4         2       4800                 2
   5         1       5100                 3
   6         1       6000                 3
   7         4       7000                 4
   8         1       8000                 5
```

How do count the changes that are in idExample, data is sorted by OrderByColumn
I need output new column that is represented by "what I want"
pay attention to "1" in IdExample. It repeats but I wants to iterate.
The query should execute quickly with the table having tens of thousands of records.

THANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `lag` and `sum` analytical function as follows:

```
Select t.*, 
       sum(case when lg is null or lg <> idexample then 1 else 0 end)
           over (order by id) as result
from
(Select t.*, 
       lag(idexample) over (order by id) as lg
  From your_table t) t
```